# Return number of rows from dplyr filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am looking for a simple piece of code to report the number of rows returned from a filter.  Using the `iris` dataset,

```
iris %>%
  filter(Species == 'setosa',
         Sepal.Length >= 5.7)
```

Three rows are returned by this statement, so I would like the output to just read '3' in the console.  Better yet, I would ultimately like to name this object 'Answer1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tally` function counts rows meeting a condition and returns a data.frame with the count in column `n`:

```
iris %>% tally(Species == 'setosa' & Sepal.Length >= 5.7)

  n
1 3
```

If you want the number alone, I guess the currently idiomatic way might be:

```
library(purrr)
iris %>% tally(Species == 'setosa' & Sepal.Length >= 5.7) %>% pluck("n")

[1] 3
```

Or if you like `filter`, just pipe to nrow:

```
iris %>% filter(Species == 'setosa', Sepal.Length >= 5.7) %>% nrow

[1] 3
```

Comment: Side note: interesting/annoying that `pluck` is not listed in purrr's documentation index.

Comment: Super plucking annoying

Answer (score -1):

```
iris %>%
    filter(Species == 'setosa', Sepal.Length >= 5.7) %>%
    count()
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your answer to the OP as well as future visitors that may come across this.